# Geometry Nodes: attribute modulo 2 is 2?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Noob on Geometry Nodes.

I'm trying to find out if a float attribute is odd or even, so I'm using *Modulo*. It works well, except when the attribute has a value of $2$, which is giving me a result of $2$ for the Modulo operation.

In the image below I'm getting the Modulo of the attribute *RowIndex* and storing it in the attribute *Direction*. It works fine with other values of *RowIndex*, but seems to glitch at $2$. I can't see what I'm doing wrong here.

[image]

Comment: If `RowIndex` is notionally an `int`, maybe you could `floor` it.

Comment: 'floor' didn't do it, but 'round' did the trick. Thanks! (I still don't know how 'RowIndex' is not an 'int', but I'll live with it.

Comment: Is RowIndex calculated by you, or is it a built-in I haven't met yet?

Comment: Maybe this RowIndex is 1.999643 for example. This modulo 2 is still 1.999643 and displayed as 2.000 (rounded).

Comment: @RobinBetts, I am calculating RowIndex. It's a float that should have only integer values per my calculations. It doesn't. Rounding it up solves the problem. Thanks for your question.

Comment: @Blunder, I believe you're exactly right. Solved the problem by rounding it up.

Comment: If you have a moment, perhaps you could answer your own question, here? (You could include the part of the tree that calculates RowIndex). That would mark it as solved, and help other folks running into  floating-point errors.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround was to use an additional attribute math node with a `Round` operation. Although the value should be clearly an integer and is shown to be an integer (2.000), Blender must have been treating it internally as a non-integer smaller than 2, hence the result. Rounding it solves the problem.

Comment: I would change the second sentence because an *integer* value is shown without decimal places (2) in the sheet. While a *float* is shown with three decimal places (2.000). For Blender, the RowIndex is clearly a _*float*_ smaller than 2. But it's displayed rounded as 2.000. Example:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8WSt.jpg

Comment: @Polterbyte If your question was solved, please be so kind and mark your answer as "Accepted Answer". This will make it easier for others to see which way leads to the solution, and the question will no longer appear as unsolved: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).